# How do I scrape text within the div(id="BodyContent") of any wikipedia article.I'm using Python's BeautifulSoup and nltk for it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nltk, wikipedia

```
page=nltk.clean_html(soup.findAll('div',id="bodyContent"))
```

When I try to run this code,It shows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\wiki3.py", line 36, in <module>
    page=nltk.clean_html(soup.findAll('div',id="bodyContent"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg\nltk\util.py", line 340, in clean_html
    cleaned = re.sub(r"(?is)<(script|style).*?>.*?(</\1>)", "", html.strip())
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving `clean_html` an iterable of `BeautifulSoup` objects (which is what `findAll` returns), not a string (which is what `clean_html` wants).

Assuming that you want a list of `div` strings that have each been cleaned, do something like:

```
page = [nltk.clean_html(str(d)) for d in soup.findAll('div',id="bodyContent")]
```

or

```
page = map(nltk.clean_html, soup.findAll('div',id="bodyContent"))
```

Comment: page = [nltk.clean_html(str(d)) for d in soup.findAll('div',id="bodyContent")] worked ....But I guess scrapping this way will not be enough to get proper text out of wikipedia html page source .... Could you suggest a way?

Comment: @user1995288: Well, what is wrong with the new output? In what ways is it not proper text?

Comment: page = [nltk.clean_html(str(d)) for d in soup.findAll('div',id="bodyContent")]                              f=codecs.open("wikiscrap","w","utf-8-sig")
f.write(page);

Comment: When I run above code It shows :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\wiki3.py", line 28, in <module>
    f.write(page);
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 691, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
  
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Comment: @user1995288: I told you that `page` will be a list of strings, not a string. You could turn it into a string with `"\n".join(page)`.

Comment: for node in soup.findAll('div',id="bodyContent"):
      page = ''.join(node.findAll(text=True))f=codecs.open("wikiscrap2","w","utf-8-sig")
f.write(page);

Comment: I read the above code somewhere ....It works and now I'm able to save wikipedia page content in utf-8 coded text file! ..

Answer (score 0):

import urllib
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import nltk
import re
import codecs

article= "Maratha Empire"
article = urllib.quote(article)

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')] #wikipedia needs this

resource = opener.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + article)
data = resource.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for node in soup.findAll('div',id="bodyContent"):
      page = ''.join(node.findAll(text=True))

f=codecs.open("wikiscrap2","w","utf-8-sig")
f.write(page);
  ................atleast with this code, I'm able to retrieve contents of wikipedia page withing bodyContent tag